# Couldn't match expected type `[a1]' with actual type `([a1], [a1])'

Tags: haskell

I am new to coding with Haskell and am stuck on this code that my professor wanted us to write. I am supposed to deal a single list into a pair of lists like so:

```
deal [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] = ([1,3,5,7], [2,4,6])
```

but I am getting this error on my 'xs' and also 'ys'

```
* Couldn't match expected type `[a1]'
                  with actual type `([a1], [a1])'
    * In the expression: deal xs
      In an equation for `xs': xs = deal xs
      In an equation for `deal':
          deal (x : y : xs : ys)
            = (x : xs, y : ys)
            where
                xs = deal xs
                ys = deal ys
    * Relevant bindings include xs :: [a1] (bound at lab2.hs:16:17)
   |
   |                 xs = deal xs
   |                      ^^^^^^^
```

Here is my code:

```hs
deal :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
deal [] = ([], [])
deal [x] = ([x], [])
deal (x:y:xs:ys) = (x:xs,y:ys)
    where
        xs = deal xs
        ys = deal ys
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is logical, since here your `deal xs` and `deal ys` will return, given the signature a 2-tuple of lists, and `xs` has type `[a]`. Note that by using the same name, you here made a recursive expression, which will not work. Using the same name multiple times is not a good idea. If you turn on warnings, the compiler will normally warn against that.

You probably want to call `deal` on the `rest` of the list, and then retrieve the two lists that you use as tails:

```
deal :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
deal [] = ([], [])
deal [x] = ([x], [])
deal (x:y:rest) = (x:xs, y:ys)
    where (xs, ys) = deal rest
```

or we can make use of [**`(***) :: a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-):

```
import Control.Arrow((***))

deal :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
deal [] = ([], [])
deal [x] = ([x], [])
deal (x:y:rest) = ((x:) *** (y:)) (deal rest)
```

an alternative is to each time swap the tuple, and append to the other side:

```
import Control.Arrow(first)
import Data.Tuple(swap)

deal :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
deal [] = ([], [])
deal (x:xs) = first (x:) (swap (deal xs))
```

we can thus define this as a `foldr` pattern:

```
import Control.Arrow(first)
import Data.Tuple(swap)

deal :: Foldable f => f a -> ([a],[a])
deal [] = foldr ((. swap) . first . (:)) ([], [])
```

This gives us the expected result:

```
Prelude> deal [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
([1,3,5,7],[2,4,6])
```

Comment: Ah, okay I understand. Thanks for enlightening me.